# Module Unavailable Error in Angular after Loading Screen in Ionic App for Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I can run my app on other devices except a Samsung S4 running android 4.4.4
I get the Module Unavailable error in the console even though the module for the entire app is instantiated properly in the .js file. All that appears after the app loading screen is a white screen.

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ShipBird 
    due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ShipBird' is not available! You either 
    misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module 
    ensure that you spec......2)

JS:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('ShipBird', ['ionic', 'ngStorage', 'ngCordova'])

    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, 
$ionicConfigProvider){

        $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);

        $stateProvider
            .state('eventmenu', {
                url: "/event",
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: "templates/event-menu.html"
            })

            .state('eventmenu.login', {
                url: '/login',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
                        controller: "LoginCtrl"
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('eventmenu.profile', {
                url: '/profile',
                params: {
                    userProfile: null
                },
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: "templates/profile.html",
                        controller: "ProfileCtrl"
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('eventmenu.claimDelivery', {
                url: "/claimDelivery",
                views: {
                    'menuContent' :{
                        templateUrl: "templates/claimDelivery.html",
                        controller: "claimDeliveryCtrl"
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('eventmenu.tutorial',{
                url:"/tutorial",
                views: {
                    'menuContent' :{
                        templateUrl: "templates/tutorial.html",
                        controller:"tutorialCtrl"
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('eventmenu.claimInfo',{
                url : "/claimDelivery/claimInfo",
                params: {
                    selectedClaimInfo: null
                },
                views:{
                    'menuContent' :{
                        templateUrl:"templates/claimInfo.html",
                        controller: "myClaimDeliveriesInfo"
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('eventmenu.myDeliveries', {
                url: "/myDeliveries",
                params: {
                    shipment_id: null,
                },
                views: {
                    'menuContent' :{
                        templateUrl: "templates/myDeliveries.html",
                        controller: "MyDeliveriesCtrl"
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('eventmenu.myDeliveriesInfo',{
                url : "/claimDelivery/myDeliveriesInfo",
                params: {
                    selectedMyDelivery: null
                },
                views:{
                    'menuContent' :{
                        templateUrl:"templates/myDeliveriesInfo.html",
                        controller: "myDeliveriesInfo"
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('eventmenu.myAvailability', {
                url: "/myAvailability",
                views: {
                    'menuContent' :{
                        templateUrl: "templates/myAvailability.html",
                        controller: "MyAvailabilityCtrl"
                    }
                }
            })
            /** Add availability (My availbility second page) **/
            .state('eventmenu.createAvailability',{
                url:"/createAvailability",
                params: {
                    isUpdate: false,
                    selectedAvailability: null
                },
                views: {
                    'menuContent' :{
                        templateUrl: "templates/addAvail.html",
                        controller :"createAvailCtrl"
                    }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("event/claimDelivery");
    });
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-
scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="
connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
http://*.shipbird.com
http://*.gstatic.com
http://*.googleapis.com
http://*.ionicframework.com
http://*.authy.com
http://*.twilio.com
http://*.amazonaws.com:3001
https://*.gstatic.com
https://*.googleapis.com
https://*.shipbird.com
https://*.authy.com
https://*.twilio.com
https://*.amazonaws.com:3001;
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
http://*.shipbird.com
http://*.gstatic.com
http://*.googleapis.com
http://*.ionicframework.com
http://*.authy.com
http://*.twilio.com
https://*.gstatic.com
https://*.googleapis.com
https://*.shipbird.com
https://*.authy.com
https://*.twilio.com;
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
http://*.shipbird.com
http://*.gstatic.com
http://*.googleapis.com
http://*.ionicframework.com
http://*.authy.com
http://*.twilio.com
https://*.gstatic.com
https://*.googleapis.com
https://*.shipbird.com
https://*.authy.com
https://*.twilio.com;
style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline'
http://*.shipbird.com
http://*.gstatic.com
http://*.googleapis.com
http://*.ionicframework.com
http://*.authy.com
http://*.twilio.com
https://*.gstatic.com
https://*.googleapis.com
https://*.shipbird.com
https://*.authy.com
https://*.twilio.com;
media-src *;">

<title></title>

<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

<!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
  }
</script>-->
<!--<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script defer async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=***&libraries=places"></script>
<!--<script src="lib/ng-map.min.js"></script>-->
<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove 
the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<!--<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>-->
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js">
</script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<!--<script 
src="https://rawgithub.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js"></script>-->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Defines PayPalPayment, PayPalPaymentDetails and PayPalConfiguration -->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic/js/cdv-plugin-paypal-
mobile-sdk.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic/js/paypal-mobile-js-
helper.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ShipBird">
```

Comment: Please show your code...

Comment: Ah i forgot sorry

Comment: There might be a problem in the loading order. Can you set up a working plunkr?